# Do method-scoped objects get destroyed when the method throws an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

```
void MyClass::method()
{
 SomeObject a;
 methodThatCanThrowException();
}
```

I wish to catch exceptions higher up the call-stack, not in `method()` - but in this example will the `SomeObject` destructor be called or not?

Comment: That's the whole point of exceptions...

Comment: No it isn't. It is one facet of exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That's why RAII works. It's why exceptions work. They wouldn't otherwise.

Full standard quote:

> **15.2 Constructors and destructors [except.ctor]**
>    **1.** As control passes from a throw-expression to a handler, destructors are invoked for all automatic objects constructed since the try block was entered. The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their construction.
>    **2.** An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has not yet begun execution. Similarly, if the non-delegating constructor for an object has completed execution and a delegating constructor for that object exits with an exception, the object’s destructor will be invoked. If the object was allocated in a new-expression, the matching deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4, 12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.
>    **3.** The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed on the path from a try block to a throw-expression is called “stack unwinding.” If a destructor called during stack unwinding exits with an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1). [ *Note: So destructors should generally catch exceptions and not let them propagate out of the destructor. —end note* ]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's sometimes called [stack unwinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding)
Catching exceptions higher up the stack is often a good idea. I've seen lots of code that catches exception when it can't do much about it.
Just make sure `SomeObject`'s destructor doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: +1 for the destructor remark. It's actually a *very strong* general rule that destructors *should never* throw exceptions.

Comment: @Angew that rule is so strong that it's even a note in the standard (see last lines of the standard quote in my answer)

Comment: @ArneMertz And for good reasons. BTW, you already had a +1 from me, just a silent one ;-)

Comment: @Angew oh I wasn't after the +1, just wanted to stress (again) the "nothrow-dtor" rule ;-)