# Understanding 'try' : C++

Tags: c++, exception

Consider below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class E{
    public:
        E(int n):m_n(n)
    {
        if (0>n)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("5");
        }
    }
        ~E(){cout << m_n << "#" <<endl;}
    public :
        int m_n;
};

int main()
{
    try{
        E a(5);
        try{
            E c(7);
            E b(-8);
            E d(9);
        }
        catch(const std::exception &e)
        {
            cout <<2 <<"&&&"<<e.what()<<endl;
            throw e;
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e)
    {
        cout <<3 << "^^^^^ "<<e.what() << endl;
        throw e;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:

```
7#
2&&&5
5#
3^^^^^ St9exception
std::exception: St9exception
Aborted.
```

Can some one please explain why such output? I expect first 5# to be displayed.

Comment: Indent the code, and you'll figure it out almost instantly.

Comment: Order of destruction is the opposite of creation.

Comment: why did SO get rid of the 'too localized' close vote? That seems somewhat appropriate here

Comment: whoever started with those yoda conditions? my brain itches everytime it has to rewrite those conditions...

Comment: @stijn Because people would use it to close perfectly valid questions like this one (though personally I'd have liked it if Gaurav had explained why he expected `5#` to be printed first, but that has nothing to do with being too localized or not).

Comment: @sepp2k: Thats exactly the point, its not perfectly well suited for SO, as the too localized close reason specified soemthing like "will likely not help future visitors"

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry ... I thought it to be part of constructor .. did not see it as part of destructor

Comment: @Najzero: It was somebody who noticed that an accidental `if (i=0)` yields a warning at best, but `if (0=i)` yields a compile error.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: you mean there are people not using `-Werror` ? (kidding, I know there are :x)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Anybody who has to compile his code with different compilers (and this includes different minor releases of `gcc`, too) yielding warnings in different cases quickly discards the idea to use `-Werror`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: not everybody, Clang compiles with `-Werror` on multiple platforms; I do agree there is a maintenance cost maybe, and you DO have to choose the set of warnings correctly as some compilers are "dumb" in certain situations and a noisy warning is worthless. But once the set of warnings is well-tuned (per compiler), it works well in general. I guess continuous integration helps tremendously though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the workflow of your program in pseudocode:

```
{
  //outer try
  create e(5);
  {
    //inner try
    create e(7);
    failed create e(-8);//exception here
    throw;
    delete e(7);//-> 7#
  }
  {
    //catch in inner try;
    cout &&&;//-> 2&&&5
    throw e; // throw sliced copy of original exception
  }
  delete e(5);//-> 5#
}
{
  //catch in outer try
  cout ^^^^;//-> 3^^^^^ St9exception (the last thrown is pure std::exception)
  throw e; // throw another copy, no more slicing as it's already exception
}
program termination because of uncaught exception;
//-> std::exception: St9exception
//-> Aborted.

//return 0; was never reached
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the construction of `b` fails, this causes the already existing `c` to be destroyed, then the inner catch to be executed.

Since it re-throws, then the already existent `a` in the outer try is destroyed and the outer catch is executed.

Since it re-trows again, and there are no more catch, the exception goes out of `main()`, where it is handled by the support library that prints the message and aborts.

The destruction order is the reverse of the construction one. So `c`, that is constructed after `a`, is destroyed before.

`b`, and `d`, never came into life.

Answer (score 0):

`#5` will be displayed when `a` is destructed. This will happen after `c` is destructed, which happens in [stack unwinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding) after you have displayed `e.what()`.