# Shutdown curent thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Edited.**

How to shutdown(to stop it forever) current thread in a class method?

Now, I have:

```
methodName() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(...);
    cv.wait(locker, [this]{return ready_ || finished_;});
    if (finished_) //need to terminate cur thread
    ...
}
```

Comment: shutdown or suspend? Those are two different things. And anyway, why not just returning?

Comment: I need to stop it forever(shut down?). It Is simplified variant of code. I need to stop thread outside ThreadFunction.

Comment: you will have to implement this yourself, or have a look at boost, they have something like this in their thread implementation

Comment: To stop a thread forever, cause it to return. You can use an atomic variable shared with the thread to signal its return, for example.

Comment: @Galik, It is simplified variant. In the real: some threads wait for conditional_variable in SomeFunc. When I have a singal in another thread(which not wait), I want to shutdown(no, not notify, shutdown) all waiting threads. How?

Comment: Instead of doing `while(true){}` You can use: `std::atomic<bool> done(false); while(!done){}`. Then if you want to kill the thread, before you wake it up with the condition variable set `done = true;`. Then the loop will end gracefully.

Comment: @Galik, ok, I am asked wrong. I am trying to write multithread class and I need to shutdown process in method. I can`t modificate ThreadFucntion.

Comment: Just `throw`. I assume you have a `try - catch` block in your main method of the thread (guarantees stack unwinding - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding)

Comment: @zahir, it seems you read prev question(I have edit it). I can`t modificate main_thread_function;

Comment: @Creris, maybe you can give some concret link`s/examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't that clear, but if you are working on windows, you cant shut any thread down using [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) or if you want to close current thread, you could use [CloseThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682659(v=vs.85).aspx).