# What could prevent a stack unwinding process in C++?

Tags: c++, stack

I'm not sure how to approach it. The question was given after a lecture about *Exceptions* so I assume it has something to do with it.

Comment: Obvious possibilities would be things like losing power at the wrong time, or simply terminating the entire process (e.g., a `kill -9` under Linux or `TerminateProcess` under Windows).

Comment: uhhh, something like exit(1)?

Comment: calling `longjmp()` would prevent proper stack unwinding but would still move the stack pointer and program counter to some earlier location (which is why it's often considered a problematic call).

Comment: I think if you throw an exception during the stack unwinding process it will just abort, idk if that counts as "preventing" though.

Answer (score 1):

Default signal handlers, or calls to `abort()` and `exit()` could prevent stack unvinding.

And there's many more situations, like pointed out in [mah's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648458/what-could-prevent-a-stack-unwinding-process-c/30648591#comment49360824_30648458).

Especially any mechanism bypassing the c++ exception model will do so. Even threads have a model to do proper stack unwinding, with having them propagated to their parents (if they weren't detached).

Comment: thanks! 
So  I get it as the stack unwinding process prevents memory leakage?

Comment: @KitKat Proper resource management is one of the reasonings, yes.

Comment: Does it do anything else?

Comment: One more special case: exception-during-unwinding causes abort() , which in tun stops unwinding (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @KitKat _"Does it do anything else?"_ It guarantees class destructors are called, whatever these will perform (closing files, detaching peripheral devices, closing network connections, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

When a scope is exited, stack unwinding starts, which means the compiler inserts calls to destructors of automatic variables, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding).

For this process to be prevented, you would need a sudden exiting of the process, which could be loss of power, force quitting the process through the command line, etc.