# Are C++ `try`/`catch` blocks the same as other blocks, regarding RAII?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, raii, noexcept

OK so if I am using a RAII idiom to manage some context attribute*, will it work as I expect if I use it nakedly in at the start of a `try` block?

In other words, if I have this:

```
struct raii {
    raii() {
        std::cout << "Scope init"
                  << std::endl; }
    ~raii() {
        std::cout << "Scope exit"
                  << std::endl; }
};
```

… and I am successfully using it like this:

```
{
    raii do_the_raii_thing;
    stuff_expecting_raii_context();
    /* … */
}
```

… will the RAII instance work the same way if I do this:

```
try {
    raii do_the_raii_thing;
    stuff_expecting_raii_context_that_might_throw();
    /* … */
} catch (std::exception const&) {
    /* … */
}
```

This is probably a dumb question, but I want to check my own sanity on this – I am fuzzy on the subtleties of `noexcept` guarantees, and other exception-related minutiae – so pardon my naíveté

---

[*] for those curious, it’s the Python C-API’s nefarious GIL (global interpreter lock) that I am managing with RAII, in my specific case

Comment: Huh, that sounds like it does involve exceptions (or at least that it _can_) – but I take it you are referring to what this question explains: http://stackoverflow.com/q/161177/298171 … yes?

Comment: Oops, the comment I was replying to has vanished!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"… will the RAII instance work the same way if I do this: ..."*

Sure they will. The *RAII instance* will go out of scope and the destructors are called before the `catch`, if an exception is thrown.

Also this will work for any upper levels, that are calling your function if you just `throw` and there aren't any `try`/`catch` blocks. That's called [*stack unwinding*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will do exactly what you want: First release the RAII resource and then process the exception block.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is specified in the [**Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf):

> **15.2 Constructors and destructors [except.ctor]**
>
> 2 The destructor is invoked for each automatic object of class type
>   constructed since the `try` block was entered. The automatic objects
>   are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their
>   construction.