# How StackFrames are impacted when GOTO is used?

Tags: c, function, memory, operating-system, stack

I am following [Memory Layout And The Stack](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/02a-Memory_Layout_And_The_Stack.php) to understand stack frames..

The Author explains stack frames nicely and says what will be in STACK at given point of time

He also asks some questions below

- Suppose a program makes 5 function calls. How many frames should be on the stack?
- We saw that the stack grows linearly downward, and that when a function returns, the last frame on the stack is deallocated and returned to unused memory. Is it possible for a frame somewhere in the middle of the stack to be returned to unused memory? If it did, what would that mean about the running program?
- Can a goto() statement cause frames in the middle of the stack to be deallocated? The answer is no, but why?
- Can longjmp() cause frames in the middle of the stack to be deallocated?

Below is my attempt to answer above questions

> - Suppose a program makes 5 function calls. How many frames should be on the stack?

If the functions are independent of each other,then only main function or main and calling function will be in stack

> We saw that the stack grows linearly downward, and that when a function returns, the last frame on the stack is deallocated and returned to unused memory. Is it possible for a frame somewhere in the middle of the stack to be returned to unused memory? If it did, what would that mean about the running program?

I think this is not possible,since this may corrupt memory

I am not sure of rest of the questions.Can you please help on this

let me know if you need more info

Comment: _Is it possible for a frame somewhere in the middle of the stack to be returned to unused memory?_ : no, it's a [__stack__](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Suppose a program makes 5 function calls. How many frames should be on the stack?

6, at the most (assuming that no function returns before all functions are been called). One for `main()` and one for every function call.

> We saw that the stack grows linearly downward, and that when a function returns, the last frame on the stack is deallocated and returned to unused memory. Is it possible for a frame somewhere in the middle of the stack to be returned to unused memory? If it did, what would that mean about the running program?

No, since a stack is a [data-structure](/questions/tagged/data-structure) that does not allow random access deletion. You can only pop from a stack.

> Can a goto() statement cause frames in the middle of the stack to be deallocated? The answer is no, but why?

Because it will alter **stack unwinding**. Exiting a code block using goto will not unwind the stack which is one of the reasons you should (almost) never use goto. Read more in [What is stack unwinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding) However, notice this is C++ related, in C goto out of block is well-defined, as Antti mentioned.

> Can longjmp() cause frames in the middle of the stack to be deallocated?

I think yes, since it's a spacial case. But that a bit contradicting to my 2nd answer.

When a "non-local goto" is executed via setjmp/longjmp, normal "stack unwinding" does not occur. Therefore any required cleanup actions will not occur either.

longjmp() function from C (see The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Caveats_and_limitations) for setjmp.h for the basics). longjmp() *jumps down the stack* to the corresponding setjmp(), across as many stack frames as there are in between. Unlike the other approaches we will see, longjmp() *does not iterate over the list of frames, it just blasts through them all at once* with wanton disregard for anything precious or beautiful that they might have contained.

Read more about it [here](http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/05/deep-wizardry-stack-unwinding.html).

`longjmp()` will return the stack to the state previously saved with `setjmp()`. If any frames in the middle are removed, then so are all frames below; i.e. there will be no "holes" in the stack after a `longjmp`, as Klas mentioned.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time  and help

Comment: OP asks about **C** not **C++**. In C `goto` out of block is well-defined.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck great comment, copy pasted in the answer. If this is a problem for you, let me know, and I will modify it! Antti, spot on, thanks!